# PHP print_r() of a path is just one letter

Tags: php, path

i have this associative array named "simulations"
it has a key "simulation_path"

i can correctly print_r $simulation but i can't do the same thing with the path
It prints JUST ONE LETTER!
Other values, corresponding to other key, are correctly printed

```
        $simulation_id=$simulation[simulation_id];
            $container_id = $simulation[container_id];
            $fullPath = simulation[simulation_path];
            print_r("fullPath\n");
            print_r($fullPath);
            print_r("\n");
```

This is the print_r() of $simulation on console

```
[container_id] => 11
[container_name] => trivial
[container_path] => /home/stefanino/public_html/gcweb/docker/users/demo/Simulations/simulat
[user_id] => 1
[simulation_id] => 9
[date_id] => 3
[simulation_path] => /home/stefanino/public_html/gcweb/docker/users/demo/Simulations/simulat/Results/12_12_15_3
[simulation_date] => 2012-12-15
```

but if I print $simulation[simulation_path] i obtain: s

Ah, something i noticed is that in chrome console, the first part of the path "/home/" is red, while the last part (the date) is green
I don't know what does it mean and if matters

Comment: `simulation['simulation_path']` is missing the `$` in front of it. Best to enable error and warning messages in PHP, or look in the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues there. If you don't pass the key as a string, PHP assumes you're referring to a constant, but by default, it returns the name of the constant if it's undefined.

You also have a typo, missing the $ sign before simulation when fetching the simulation_path.

You should be writing something like this:

```php
<?php

   $simulation_id=$simulation["simulation_id"];
   $container_id = $simulation["container_id"];
   $fullPath = $simulation["simulation_path"];
   print_r("fullPath\n");
   print_r($fullPath);
   print_r("\n");
```